# Sci-fi story with androids, nano-machines, robot dogs and time travel

Tags: story-identification, movie, androids, space-station

My memories of the plot are vague, but in the end, a female android was caught in a huge explosion and sent back in time. I don't know when it was made or exactly when I watched it, but it may have been on Netflix.

Here are all the details I remember:

- It's live action, with any effects being low-budget.
- The lead was a female android with relatively short blonde hair, I'm pretty sure introduced without clothes.
- There might have been another, male, android.
- There was one either Hispanic or Caucasian actor with black hair, and a similarly tanned and black-haired actress that was turned into a zombie by nano-machines but managed to keep some individuality.
- They were all on a space station, and are armed for some reason.
- There are nano-machines that first turn you into zombies, then robot dog things. The robot dog things were poorly animated, and had no turning animation; when they hit a corner, they abruptly switched to a front-facing view.
- As previously mentioned, it was all very low budget, with bad blood effects, but they had a good lens.
- The male android (if he was an android) was the antagonist, aside from the nano-machines.

In the end, the lead android was trying to get a bomb, or something that was about to explode off of the station, and gets caught in the explosion and sent back in time, coming down in a desert and being found by some people. She is broken and is repeating a warning that becomes a self-fulfilling prophecy, culminating in the explosion.

Comment: Your title made me think it was a written "story", but then you say "poorly animated"--is the whole thing an animation (and if so, did it look like anime, western animation, or what?), or are you just talking about an animated special effect in a live-action production? 2D animation or CG/stop-motion? You might want to edit your title to make this more clear. And was it TV show length or movie length? Also, do you remember about when you saw it? Did it look like it was from the same approximate period you saw it or was it older?

Comment: Parts of the premise remind me of what I've seen of the Dead Space films.

Comment: It was a live-action movie. Will edit.

Comment: Robot dogs, time travel = Doctor Who! Lol

Comment: @Anonymous: 
But the robot dogs were animated?

Comment: @Sean Duggan: Poorly, but yes. They were animated in a visual style akin to stop-motion, but I'm not 100% sure exactly the method with which they were animated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much searching, I have finally found the title of this movie: [Total Retribution](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2175184/)

[image]

Thanks to everyone who commented!